# Dangerous javascript inside form action

Tags: javascript, escaping

I have the following form :

```
<form action="javascript:myFunction(USER_INPUT)">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The problem is that it receives the USER_INPUT from the user side. And it can be: `100);alert(10)//`;

which results in execution of `alert()`

What is the best way to resolve this issue ?

Comment: How is `USER_INPUT` filled into the function?

Comment: It's created in Java.

Comment: sanitize it at server. No point even trying with javascript since it's very easy to bypass javscript

Comment: Is there any limit on what could be the input in GET parameters ? I want to remove anything after `)` or anything after `;` . In general, is it possible to have these two characters in the GET parameters ?

Comment: you should probably frame this question from the server side rather than the client

Comment: it's as possible to limit input through javascript as it is possible to edit or delete javascript and submit arbitrary input to your server.

Comment: Use a anti-XSS library on the server side whenever you receive user input. One example: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project